# Get data from an EventMachine server connection?

Tags: sinatra, rack, eventmachine

I'm attempting to create a Sinatra server that will return statistics about an EventMachine server. That is, I'm running:

```
EventMachine.run do
    server = EventMachine.start_server 'localhost', 3333, MyApp

    dispatch = Rack::Builder.app do
        map '/' do
            run MySinatraApp
        end
    end

    Rack::Server.start({
        app: dispatch,
        server: 'thin',
        Host: '0.0.0.0',
        Port: '1111'
    })
end
```

My goal is to figure out information on that running server started by `start_server`, such as `connection_count`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no in-built way to do this (hopefully someone disproves me),

you can keep a counter in `MyApp` and `+1` on connect and `-1` on unbind for same effect.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to access `MyApp` information from that server instance? Obviously I can't use `MyApp.new` but I don't know of a way to pull info from `MyApp` that's started using `start_server`.

Comment: Sorry :/ completely forgot of this question, hopefully you managed, it's not complicated

Comment: I did, thanks! I just made class variables to hold the information rather than instance variables, and use those in the Sinatra server.

Answer (score 0):

Why? Why not just have the EM server provide a `/info` endpoint or something that returns a dump of the information you need? Why do you need the second server?  If you really want a second server then it could just be a simple sinatra app that makes a HTTP request to `/info` and returns the results.

For `connection_count` it looks like there is a `EM.connection_count` you can call.  You can see it [here](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/3203c402e78e2661c11cfca1f1d0b81f32a09688/lib/eventmachine.rb#L928).